# In R, I would like to find copies within columns. Then combine those row values, and If they are a string we add, if numeric, the mean

Tags: r

I am trying to make a code that finds duplicates in a specific column, df$Proteins. When found, I would like the duplicate rows of that column and all other columns to be combined, adding strings together. Rows were

```
row1otherColumn <- a 
row2otherColumn <- b
```

now are

```
CombinedRowotherColumn <- a@b
```

Also, if the columns are numeric then I would like the `mean`.

```
row1otherColumn1 <- 1 
row2otherColumn1 <- 2
```

now are

```
CombinedRowotherColumn1 <- 1.5
```

Thanks!

Comment: `aggregate(.~Proteins, df, \(x)if(inherits(x, 'numeric'))mean(x) else paste(x, collapse='@'))`

Answer (score 1):

Without a reproducible example this is hard to answer, and syntax like `row1$column` is not clear to me (are `row1` and `row2` different data.frames?), but probably something along the lines of:

```
library(tidyverse)
your_data %>%
  group_by(Protein) %>%
  summarise(
    across(where(is.numeric), mean),
    across(where(\(col) !is.numeric(col), \(v) paste(v, sep = '@')))
  )
```